# In what language do the wizards and witches from non-English-speaking countries cast their spells in?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

As long as spells of Harry Potter world goe, most famous ones are in [Latin and some Greek](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/07/spells-harry-potter/). But the magical community is not only specifically situated in English-speaking countries, since there are schools in other countries as well, like in Russia, France, and Japan.

My question is **are there any spells which don't have their origins in Latin or Greek? Do other non-English countries also use same spells, or do they have their own language counterparts?**

Comment: Hamlet's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15238/20774) in the dupe mentions at least one non-European origin spell

Comment: While I'm not aware of the canon, wouldn't it just be the language family of the country of origin of the spell?

Comment: Ohk thanks, appreciate it :)

Comment: You only need the word "in" once in your question. You can erase either the first or last word to avoid tautology.