# Half-Blood Prince's Journal

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter book series Harry finds Snape's (Half-Blood Prince) old Potions journal. Not only does it help him with potions tremendously, (let's face it, Harry is a total science fluke) it also shows him new spells Snape created to probably use on James' band of hoodlums for picking on him, as well as other bullies.

**First question:** How does one make up their own spell? Any steps at all? (Remember references please.)

**Second question:** What other list of spells and information besides potions resides in Snape's old diary/ potions notebook? (Again please cite and reference.) Thank you!

Comment: First question is answered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5078/3267)

Comment: This isn't entirely relevant as everyone knows what you're referring to, but the pedantic side of me won't leave it alone... It's Snape's old potions **textbook**, not a journal/diary/notebook - granted, it was heavily annotated, but it was a textbook and that's how Harry ended up with it to begin with, otherwise he would never have had it in the first place. Ok - pedant satisfied :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is on the Harry Potter wikia information about Spell Creation though not much goes into how it's done...

http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_creation

It lists a various amount of sources and citations even alleging that Lockhart was capable of doing so in the Behinds the Scenes section..

> It is possible that Gilderoy Lockhart was a spell inventor, as he
>   seemed to make several spells (Deboning, Peskipiksi Pesternomi, etc.)
>   up on the spot. This would explain why he did not expect them to work
>   the way they did all of them producing the correct effect
>   (etymologically speaking) bar Peskipiksi Pesternomi.

Anyway the website shows the list of wizards whom created spells and which ones including the ones Snape did.

> Severus Snape
>
> Langlock
>
> Muffliato
>
> Sectumsempra
>
> Levicorpus
>
> Liberacorpus
>
> Vulnera
>
> Sanentur
>
> All spells recorded in his copy of Advanced Potion Making were also crafted by him. Created between 1977 and 1978

Comment: I thought Vulnera Sanentur was one singular spell?

Answer (score 2):

Wikia has a list of non-potion spells [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Severus_Snape%27s_copy_of_Advanced_Potion-Making) (with references).

They are  Sectumsempra, Levicorpus, Liberacorpus (counterspell), Langlock and Muffliato; as well as Toenail Growth Hex.

As Kevin noted, the creation of new spells is discussed on SFF.SE before: [Can wizards create their own spells?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5078/can-wizards-create-their-own-spells)