# What does it mean to create a spell?

Tags: harry-potter

The Harry Potter series discusses many spells created by particular wizards like Snape and Voldemort. What does it really mean to *create* a spell?

Does the creator select a befitting Latin phrase and certain wand movements to channel the magic inherent in him? More importantly, how does he/she seal these for use by all future wizards?

The first may be all right, since it seems suggested in the series that, *in principle* (i.e., with sufficient ability, expertise in channelling magic etc.), any spell could work non-verbal and wandless. It is the second subquestion above that demands an answer.

After all, every spell discussed had to be created at some point in the past, since Latin had a beginning in history.

Comment: Is there something you're looking for not already covered in [Can wizards create their own spells?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5078/can-wizards-create-their-own-spells)

Comment: It's not covered how can a sorcerer protect his newly created spell. And, at least, imo, maybe it was something similar to the hex Voldemort placed on its name, but without the part where a death eater comes to kill you afterwards

Comment: @Oak what do you mean "protect"?

Comment: @Kevin Well, basicly, restrict that specific unnammed spell to a specific body movement and / or oral pronounciation